# How to remove a specific child in Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Instead of setting the data to `null` from the child of  **table** `Driver`.. I want that specific  `child` to be removed.

Here is my sample code.

```
driverRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_DRIVER);
                    Query pendingBus = driverRef.orderByChild("busNum").equalTo(busNum);
                    pendingBus.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String busnumber = snapshot.child("busNum").getValue().toString();
                                String empID = snapshot.child("empId").getValue().toString();

                                if (busnumber.equals(busNum)) {

                                    snapshot.getRef().child("age").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("busNum").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("driversName").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("empId").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("latitude").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("longitude").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("password").setValue("");
                                    snapshot.getRef().child("username").setValue("");
}
}
```

and this is the output of that method `setValue`
[image: Output]

Comment: Please post your database structure. Setting null as a value of a child is the same as removing a child

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `setValue` to `null`
I use `.removeValue`
Example: `snapshot.getRef().child("age").removeValue();`

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me

```
databaseReference = databaseReference.child("Users").child(mobile);
databaseReference.setValue(null);
```